# Dynamic LINQ Multiple Where Clause

Tags: c#, linq, autocomplete, where-clause

Still really struggling with this and appear to be going round in circles.

I have the following code that is driving me nuts. It should populate a list of items to be used in an autocomplete text box:

```
public string[] GetAutoComplete(string prefixText, int count)
    {
            string memberid = HttpContext.Current.Session["MemberID"].ToString(); 
            string locationid = HttpContext.Current.Session["LocationID"].ToString();
            string inhouse = HttpContext.Current.Session["Inhouse"].ToString();
            string supplier = HttpContext.Current.Session["Supplier"].ToString();
            string groupw = HttpContext.Current.Session["Group"].ToString();
            string external = HttpContext.Current.Session["External"].ToString();

            MyEnts autocomplete = new MyEnts();

            var r = from p in autocomplete.tblAutoCompletes
                        where p.MemberId == memberid && p.LocationId == locationid && p.ACItem.Contains(prefixText)
                        select p.ACItem;

            if (inhouse == "Inhouse")
                r = r.Where(p => p == inhouse);

            if (supplier == "Supplier")
                r = r.Where(p => p == supplier);

            if (groupw == "Group")
                r = r.Where(p => p == groupw);

            if (external == "External")
                r = r.Where(p => p == external);

            r.OrderBy(p => p);

            return r.ToArray();
```

What I am trying to retrieve with the dynamic where clause along the lines of the following.

Should inhouse = "Inhouse", then the list of items should include the word "Inhouse". If inhouse != "Inhouse", the word "Inhouse" should be excluded from the list.

This same logic should then be applied across the different where clauses i.e. Supplier, Group, External.

I genuinely have tried lots of different methods but I cannot for the life of me get the thing to work and it's frustrating me somewhat.

If anyone can suggest a way of doing this, you will either get a big kiss or a big frosty beer should our paths ever cross.

Comment: I don't understand your objective here, if the `ACItem` contains the prefix text then surely you'd want all entries that do so. Secondly, one would assume from your code that ACItem is string returned from your object so you subsequent comparisons are going to fail unless ACItem is "Inhouse", "Supplier", "Group", or "External". In effect you are creating a routine to provide auto complete for 4 words. Is ACItem, as I suspect, more complex than just a string?

Comment: Aside from anything else, your ordering is doing nothing - you need `r = r.OrderBy(p => p);`

Comment: Hello Lazarus (well done on coming back from the dead by the way, great come back that). ACItem is a column containing the list of autocomplete items to be returned. My scenario includes user preferences (through the sessions)whereby I might want to restrict what the user can have access too. So if they are not allowed to see Inhouse, the autocomplete list would not show these items.

If it's not possible, or extremely tricky for a simpleton like me,  I might just end up leaving them in the list and put some validation once they have selected the item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure about your problem here but if you want to exclude then shouldn't the code be something like

```
 if (inhouse == "Inhouse")
                r = r.Where(p => p == inhouse);
 else
                r = r.Where(p => p != inhouse);
```

Oh! if you want just exclusion then the code should be something like

```
if (inhouse != "Inhouse")
                    r = r.Where(p => p != inhouse);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the set of values to include/exclude is known at compile-time (as appears to be the case in your example), I think this can be managed with one query:

```
string memberid = HttpContext.Current.Session["MemberID"].ToString(); 
string inhouse = HttpContext.Current.Session["Inhouse"].ToString();
string supplier = HttpContext.Current.Session["Supplier"].ToString();

bool includeInHouse = (inhouse == "Inhouse");
bool includeSupplier = (supplier == "Supplier");

MyEnts autocomplete = new MyEnts();

var r = from p in autocomplete.tblAutoCompletes
            where (p.MemberId == memberid && p.LocationId == locationid && p.ACItem.Contains(prefixText))
            && (includeInHouse || (p.ACItem != "InHouse"))
            && (includeSupplier || (p.ACItem != "Supplier"))
            select p.ACItem;

r.OrderBy(p => p.ACItem);

return r.ToArray();
```

I've eliminated a couple cases for brevity.

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't each of your Where clauses just need to contain a Contains criteria and some Not Contains?

```
if (inhouse == "Inhouse")
     r = r.Where(p => p.Contains(inhouse) && !p.Contains("Supplier") && !p.Contains("Group") && !p.Contains("External"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorted.

var r = from p in autocomplete.tblAutoCompletes
                        where p.MemberId == memberid && p.LocationId == locationid && p.ACItem.Contains(prefixText)
                        select p.ACItem;

```
        if (inhouse != "Inhouse")
            r = r.Where(p => p != "Inhouse");

        if (supplier != "Supplier")
            r = r.Where(p => p != "Supplier");

        if (groupw != "Group")
            r = r.Where(p => p != "Group");

        if (external != "External")
            r = r.Where(p => p != "External");

        r = r.OrderBy(p => p);

        return r.ToArray();
```

I had to set the exception in quotation marks as the session vlaue was inappropriate and wouldn't have picked out anything from the list.

Thanks to all those contributing and helping me out.

Comment: oh well, no beer, no kiss :( - glad you got it sorted :)

Comment: Jim - keep your eyes posted to my questions. Very new to all of this so plenty more opportunites for beer and kisses!!!