# C# Using Linq Query with where clause as variable on dataTable

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, where-clause, linq-to-objects

I have seen different examples and questions but I cannot figure how to write this query successfully. The where clause condition is in filter.condition

```
  private object[] GetValueFromLookup(MultipleKeyConditionBuilder filter, string lookupValueField, DataTable datatableLookup)
    {

        Func<int, string> whereClause = test => filter.Condition;

        IEnumerable<object> query =
        from rows in datatableLookup.AsEnumerable().Where(whereClause)
        select rows.Field<object>(lookupValueField);
        return query.ToArray();

    }
```

I am getting this error. I have tried different things but unfortunately I cannot understand how to solve it.

> cannot convert from 'System.func (int,string)' to 'System.func(system.Data.DataRow,int,bool)'

MultipleKeyConditionBuilder.This function gives the filter condition. It is defined as.

```
public MultipleKeyConditionBuilder(List<string> sourceKeyFieldsList, List<string> referenceKeyFieldsList, DataRow sourceRow) {}
```

filter.Condition gives a string for example "Project_id = 255454"

Comment: Edit your question and throw some light on `MultipleKeyConditionBuilder`

Comment: Can there be more than one condition? What will be value of filter.Condition in case of multiple filters?

Comment: yes it has more than 1 condition,. depending on the situation. ' Condition += referenceKeyFieldsList[i].ToValidSQLName() + " = " + filterChar + sourceRow[sourceKeyFieldsList[i]] + filterChar; '

Comment: You should give a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501709/dynamic-linq-multiple-where-clause

Comment: And also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848415/dynamic-where-clause-in-linq

Comment: hmm in my case its just a single string which has all conditions. I think i need to change my approach. this filter will not work for Linq

Comment: If you can change the filter creation then it is possible easily.

Comment: thank you for your help I will try it

Answer (score 1):

You can use a declaration like this

```
 Func<DataRow, bool> whereClause = test => filter.Condition;
```

I assume that `filter.Condition` returns a boolean value. I have tested this simplification:

```
 Func<DataRow, bool> whereClause = test => true;
```

**Update**:

`filter.Condition`returns a string with statements like `property = 'value'`. This has to evaluated with some function that takes this statement, inserts the values from the current DataRow and returns a boolean, like

```
    ...
    Func<DataRow, bool> whereClause = row => SomeClass.Evaluate(filter.Condition, row);
    ...

public static class SomeClass
{
     public static bool Evaluate(string expression, DataRow data)
     {
          ... do some sophisticated stuff ...
          return true /  false;
     }
}
```

But this solution is only fitting to give a direct answer to the question.

I suggest the redesign the `MultipleKeyConditionBuilder` that `MultipleKeyConditionBuilder.Condition` does not return a `string` but a `Predicate<DataRow>`. After that you can write

```
Func<DataRow, bool> whereClause = test => filter.Condition(test);
```

Comment: filter.Condition returns a string

Comment: now only the last part is different. how to change it to bool or the other to string?

Comment: How is the MultipleKeyConditionBuilder defined?

Comment: public MultipleKeyConditionBuilder(List<string> sourceKeyFieldsList, List<string> referenceKeyFieldsList, DataRow sourceRow)
        {}

Comment: And `MultpileKeyConditionBuilder.Condition` ?

Comment: its gives filter condition. for example the current value is "Project_Id = 254411"

Comment: Is this a string ?

Comment: Func<DataRow, bool> whereClause = test => Convert.ToBoolean(filter.Condition); I tried this it gives String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It looks complex but I will try something new

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have complicated the things there.

This should do the job.

```
private object[] GetValueFromLookup(MultipleKeyConditionBuilder filter, string lookupValueField, DataTable datatableLookup)
{
    DataRow[] rows = datatableLookup.Select(filter.Condition);
    return rows.Select(r => r.Field<object>(lookupValueField)).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: The datatableLookup.Select is slow. I want to improve the performance. That's why I am using Linq. I tried dataview it was also not beneficial

Comment: @Masood  Edit your question and throw some light on `MultipleKeyConditionBuilder`. How you are preparing the filter?

Comment: This function is adding strings to condition variable to make a condition: it is perfect for data table select statement but for linq its not working

Answer (score 0):

System.Linq.Enumerable.Where expects a `Func<T, bool>` (i.e. a function that takes T as input and returns bool)
meaning for your line `whereClause = test => filter.Condition;` to work `filter.Condition` should be C# code. In your case it seems to be a string.

If I understand what you are trying to do here then you should have your `filter.Condition` return an `Expression<Func<DataRow, bool>>`.

Following is a code snippet to help you understand how Expressions work.

```
        Expression<Func<string, bool>> conditionExpression = x => "MyString".Equals(x);

        // Following if block will not compile
        //if (conditionExpression("MyString")) 
        //    Console.WriteLine("True");
        //else
        //    Console.WriteLine("False");

        var condition = conditionExpression.Compile();

        // Following if block will compile.
        if(condition("MyString")) //this compiles.
            Console.WriteLine("True");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("False");
```

Hope this helps.